# How to read and load the internal storage .csv file in webview

Tags: android, csv, webview, xamarin.android, android-webview

I am working in xamarin android project. I am downloading .CSV file and store it in internal storage. File path is given below.
**filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc.def/files/ABC/MyListSample.csv**

I want to load this .csv file into webview. I tried the below given code but couldn't able to load the .csv file in webview.

```
_webview = (WebView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.webView);

_webview.SetInitialScale (0);
        _webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        _webview.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows (false);
        _webview.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        _webview.Settings.SetPluginState (WebSettings.PluginState.On);//Try
        _webview.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = false;
        _webview.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;

_webview.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

_webview.LoadUrl(string.Format("file://" + filepath));
```

Second method I tried is given below:

```
 Java.IO.File csv = new Java.IO.File(filepath);

 _webview.LoadUrl(string.Format("file://" + csv));
```

I don't want any third party library like open csv to view/load this csv file. I have searched a lot and tried many methods but couldn't able to find solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a sample to test your code. I can open the .html file and the image file with it, but I got a blank webview when I try to load the .csv file.

It seems the webview doesn't support to open the .csv file directly. But I used the following code to open a .csv file online by the google documents view.

```
 _webview.LoadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv");
```

But this code can't load the internal storage .csv file. So you can try to upload the .csv to a server.

Comment: Are you sure, the webview doesn't support to open the .csv file? Is there any other way or any workaround methods to load the internal storage .csv file?

Comment: The other files such as image and html can be opened directly. And most solutions of reading the data from the .csv on the SO use the third party plugins. But you can try to open it with the browser. But the browser may not also open it.@Muthukumaaran